# ElasticSearch 0.90.5 throws occasional NoNodeAvailableException using Java API

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ElasticSearch 0.90.5. Single node cluster and using Java API for all communication to the node (both for indexing and searching).

I have a continuous stream of documents being fed into the server every 10 mins. Using Bulk indexing API for optimal performance. Subsequent queries either retrieve a single document or run More-Like-This queries.

Every now and then (sometimes a bit too often) we get the following exception :

**Caused by: org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: No node available**

I can assure you that the server is up and running just fine. This is an occasional issue we see. NewRelic Server monitor shows very little strain on the box itself. Highest CPU usage was **50%** that too during a small time period. ES logs are not showing me anything useful. No GC messages in logs for the affected time periods.

Has anyone else encountered this exception when using the API. Any insights will be appreciated.

Relevant stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: No node available
        at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$RetryListener.onFailure(TransportClientNodesService.java:249)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.TransportActionNodeProxy$1.handleException(TransportActionNodeProxy.java:84)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$Adapter$2$1.run(TransportService.java:311)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you post full stack trace by any chance?

Also by looking through elasticsearch message board (http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/) for similar exceptions, you might want to try to increase `client.transport.ping_timeout` and see if that would help

Comment: we already have client.transport.ping_timeout set to 10s ... will add a part of the stack trace to my question up

Comment: while reviewing the code, i had missed the timeout on one of the two clusters we connect to. Also adding client.transport.sniff to true on the client api initialization (one of our clusters is 3 nodes and i want the connections to at least be distributed fairly). Will report back if this helps. Thanks for the reminder though on this setting. Made me double check.